# What is the difference between def and defonce in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, lisp, clojurescript

What is the difference between **def** and **defonce** in Clojure?

When to use **def** over **defonce** or vice versa?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`defonce` is skipped when variable is already defined.

```clj
user> (def a 1) ;;=> #'user/a
user> a ;;=> 1
user> (def a 2) ;;=> #'user/a
user> a ;;=> 2
user> (defonce b 1) ;;=> #'user/b
user> b ;;=> 1
user> (defonce b 2) ;;=> nil
user> b ;;=> 1
```

Answer (score 8):

Defonce only binds the name to the root value if the name has no root value.

For example, like [Jay Fields blogs](http://blog.jayfields.com/2012/05/agile-development-with-clojure.html) about, it can be used in conjunction when you want to reload namespaces but you might not need to reload all.

```
(defonce ignored-namespaces (atom #{}))

(defn reload-all []   
  (doseq [n (remove (comp @ignored-namespaces ns-name) (all-ns))]
    (require (ns-name n) :reload )))
```

Answer (score 1):

As for when to use `defonce`, if you're using system with hot reloading (CLJS with mount and re-frame for example), `defonce` is useful to keep the state between reloads.

Similar situation when you re-evaluate source file yourself (e.g. in REPL) but want to keep the value of the var bound to the symbol.